# How to find out if a subset of variable is more statistically significant for the dependent variable than another level of the same variable

Tags: r

I have a hypothesis which is: Support of the EMU is more important for those within the EMU, than outside of it.

The variables are as such:
EMU: 1, within EMU; 0, outside of EMU
EU_Support: 1, Support; 0, don’t support

My code looks like this:

```
EB734_May_2010_model_u <- glm(trust ~ D_economy + (Support_EMU*EMU), family = binomial, data = EB734_May_2010)
```

Can someone help me if this is the right way to go about testing thing hypothesis out?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I cooked up some fake data that will help illustrate the point.  Here are the data and the model:

```
df <- tibble(
  EMU = sample(c(0,1), 1000, prob=c(.75,.25), replace=TRUE), 
  Support_EMU = sample(c(0,1), 1000, replace=TRUE), 
  z = rnorm(1000), 
  eta = EMU + .25*Support_EMU + 2*Support_EMU*EMU + z, 
  p = plogis(eta), 
  y = rbinom(1000, 1, p)
)

mod <- glm(y ~ EMU*Support_EMU + z, data=df, family=binomial)
summary(mod)

# Call:
#   glm(formula = y ~ EMU * Support_EMU + z, family = binomial, data = df)
# 
# Deviance Residuals: 
#   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
# -2.7554  -0.9769   0.3717   0.9175   2.3001  
# 
# Coefficients:
#                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)      -0.0601     0.1115  -0.539  0.58977    
# EMU               1.3788     0.2661   5.183 2.19e-07 ***
# Support_EMU       0.3237     0.1582   2.046  0.04080 *  
# z                 0.9455     0.0878  10.768  < 2e-16 ***
# EMU:Support_EMU   1.4732     0.4897   3.008  0.00263 ** 
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
# 
# Null deviance: 1344.4  on 999  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance: 1090.0  on 995  degrees of freedom
# AIC: 1100
# 
# Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

What you're really interested in is evaluating the effect of the interaction.  You really want the second difference of the equation above with respect to the predicted probabilities.  That is, you want (for E=EMU and S=Support_EMU):

[Pr(y=1|E=1,S=1,z) - Pr(y=1|E=1,S=0,z)] - [Pr(y=1|E=0,S=1,z)-Pr(y=1|E=0,S=0,z)]

Another way of putting this is:

[Effect of S when E=1] - [Effect of S when E=0]

The `secondDiff()` function in the package I wrote, `DAMisc` does just this.  It uses a parametric bootstrap to calculate confidence intervals for the effects.  One way of doing this is using the "marginal effect at reasonable values" (MER) approach, where we hold all variables not involved in the interaction at their median values.  The result here is:

```
s1 <- secondDiff(mod, c("EMU", "Support_EMU"), df, method="MER")
summary(s1)
# Second Difference Using the Marginal Effect at Typical Values Approach
# 
# Average Second Difference: 0.087, 95% CI: (-0.019,0.203)
```

This says that on average the first difference in probabilities for a change in S from 0 to 1 using the MER approach is 0.087 *bigger* when EMU is 1 than when EMU is 0.  However, the confidence interval suggests it's not a statistically significant difference.  Alternatively, you could use the "average marginal effect" (AME) approach.  Here, we calculate the second difference separately for every observation holding all of the other variables at their observed values in the dataset.  This gives us a second difference for every observation.  We then take the average of those second differences as the effect.  Here's what that looks like.

```
s2 <- secondDiff(mod, c("EMU", "Support_EMU"), df, method="AME")
summary(s2)

# Second Difference Using the Average Marginal Effect Approach
# 
# Overall: 
#   Average Second Difference: 0.114, 95% CI: (0.005,0.224)
# 
# Individual:
#   Significant Negative Individual Second Differences: 0 
#   Significant Positive Individual Second Differences: 369 
#   Insignificant Individual Second Differences: 631
```

This says that on average (across all observations) the effect of S when EMU=1 is .114 bigger than the effect of S when EMU=0 and that is statistically significant according to the confidence interval.  The other part of the output suggests that of the 1000 second differences 631 of them are insignificant and 369 are significant and positive.

You can install the most recent version of the `DAMisc` package by first installing the `remotes` package and then doing:

```
remotes::install_github("davidaarmstrong/damisc")
```

As for the difference between the AME and MER approaches, there is an interesting article on the subject you can get [here](https://gvpt.umd.edu/sites/gvpt.umd.edu/files/pubs/Hanmer%20and%20Kalkan%20AJPS%20Behind%20the%20Curve.pdf) by Michael Hanmer and Ozan Kalkan.

Comment: You’re a genius!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment - I got this code: Error in data[[x]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable @Dave - any ideas on why this may be so?

Comment: @AnriSakakibara Usually this type of error means that you've specified something like `data=data` or `data=df` when those objects do not exist in the workspace.  I suspect this is because you didn't replace `df` in the `secondDiff()` function with your data frame.  Are you doing `s2 <- secondDiff(mod, c("EMU", "Support_EMU"), EB734_May_2010, method="AME")`?

Comment: Hi @Dave, thanks for your reply again. That was the case - but then I ran into this error message: Error in UseMethod("central") : 
  no applicable method for 'central' applied to an object of class "c('haven_labelled', 'vctrs_vctr', 'double') when using the "MER" method. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @AnriSakakibara you can solve the problem by changing the variables in your model to numeric.  For example, 

`library(dplyr)`
`tmp <- EB734_May_2010 %>% `
`  select(trust, Support_EMU, EMU, D_economy) %>%`
`  mutate_all(.funs=las.numeric)`

Then, replace `EB734_May_2010` with `tmp` in the model and subsequent `secondDiff()` functions

Comment: Would this be changing the dependent variable, or independent variable to numeric? They are currently factor variables with "0" and "1" as the levels.

Comment: @AnriSakakibara, you could leave the factors as is, it's the variables you didn't change to factors that are causing the problems.  The ones that are currently of class `haven_labelled` need to be changed to numeric.

Comment: Hi Dave - thank you so so much for all your help so far. Final question - Error in preds %*% D : non-conformable arguments any idea on why this is coming up?

Comment: Hi Anri, hard to know without the data, could you possibly send the data and code you're using to me: dave@quantoid.net